# How to add a UIBarButtonItem programmatically to UINavigationBar dragged onto view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have searched and looked at multiple solutions to this problem but can't seem to have anything work for me. Here is my code and a screenshot. If it makes any difference I manually dragged the navigation bar onto the view and connected an outlet.Thanks. I appreciate any help on this.[image]

```
class SubjectsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet var noBooksLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var navigationBarTitle: UINavigationBar!

    func backAction() -> Void {

        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        self.noBooksLabel.hidden = true

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        descriptions.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
        usernames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
        imageFiles.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

        println("Subject view controller")

        self.navigationBarTitle.topItem?.title = "\(selectedSubject)"

        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "backAction")

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton


        pickedSubject = selectedSubject

        println("Picked Subject = \(pickedSubject)")

        println("Subject view controller")

        self.navigationBarTitle.topItem?.title = "\(selectedSubject)"

        //let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "backAction")
        //self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=barBtn;

        var subjectQuery = PFQuery(className: "BookPosting")

        subjectQuery.whereKey("CourseSubject", equalTo: pickedSubject)
        subjectQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {

            (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                // The find succeeded.
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) scores.")

                // Do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

                    for object in objects {

                        descriptions.append(object["Description"] as String)

                        usernames.append(object["username"] as String)

                        imageFiles.append(object["imageFile"] as PFFile)

                        self.myTableView.reloadData()

                    }

                }

                println("descriptions.count = \(descriptions.count)")



                if (descriptions.count == 0) {

                    self.noBooksLabel.hidden = false

                } else {

                    self.noBooksLabel.hidden = true

                }

            } else {

                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error) \(error.userInfo!)")

            }

        }

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return descriptions.count

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 100

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell: bookCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("booksCells") as bookCell


        cell.subjectBookDescription.text = descriptions[indexPath.row]
        cell.subjectBookPosterUsername.text = usernames[indexPath.row]

        imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                let image = UIImage(data: imageData)

                cell.subjectBookImage.image = image

            }

        }

        return cell
    }




}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are trying to add a UIBarButtonItem to the navigation bar connected to the outlet navigationBarTitle.

Replace `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton` with the following:

```
self.navigationBarTitle.topItem?.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```